# Cómo hacer peticiones en paralelo usando fetch + async?

Tags: javascript, fetch, async

Intento realizar 2 peticiones en paralelo usando fetch y async, esto debido a que necesito cierta información para arrancar mi app de practica apenas inicie el server, lo que intento es algo como esto:

```
async function consultas(urls){
Promise.all(['1url','2url'].map()=> ....) 
}
```

Pero estoy estancado, como podría solucionarlo
agradezco la ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El camino es correcto solo falta aplicar el await para esperar la salida final en tu Promise.all y combinarlo con fetch, finalmente puedes usar IIFE para que arranque tu archivo al inicio del svr como deseas.

```
const urls = [
  'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/7/',
  'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/150/'
]

async function querys (urls){
  try {
    const result = await Promise.all(urls.map(url=> fetch(url).then((res)=>res.json())))
  return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

(async()=>{
  console.log(await querys(urls))
})()
```

Hago el ejemplo practica para que lo veas enseguida,saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para esperar que la peticion finalice deberias utilizar 'await' para permitir a la promesa ser resuelta.

```
const results = await Promise.all(['1url','2url'])
results.map()=> ....
```